# Form page in replace function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

> Form page:

```
%%[ 
    set @travelinterest= RequestParameter("tli")



    set @favouritebcdestination = RequestParameter("bcd")

    set @email = "testingprupose1@gmail.com"


    UpdateData("B2CSubscribe_AN",1,"Email",@email,"Travelinterest",Replace(@travelinterest,",",";"),"Favouritebcdestination",Replace(@favouritebcdestination,",",";"))
]%%
```

> Amp script :

```
%%[

VAR @email, @acts, @acts2, @acts3, @cnt_product

SET @rowset = LookupRows("DENAME","Email","somemail@gmail.com")
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)

set @email = "somemail@gmail.com"
set @act = Field(@row,"DENAME")

set @productrowset = BuildRowsetFromString(@act,";")
FOR @cnt_product = 1 to RowCount(@productrowset) Do
set @record_product = Field(Row(@productrowset,@cnt_product),1)

IF @record_product == "Arts" or  @record_product == "Culture and Historical Experiences" THEN

     SET @var1 = "Arts"
     SET @var2 = "Culture and Historical Experiences"
     SET @record_product = Concat(@var1, "," , @var2)
ENDIF


IF @record_product == "Aboriginal Culture and Experiences" THEN
SET @acts = "checked"


ELSEIF @record_product == "Arts,Culture and Historical Experiences" THEN
SET @acts1 = "checked"


ELSE
SET @acts12 = "checked"
ENDIF

Next @cnt_product

]%%
```

In form page the values are displayed in three checkbox like:

1. Aboriginal Culture and Experiences
2. Arts,Culture and Historical Experiences
3. Driving Vacations

**below that submit button will be there?**

after clicking the checkbox the values are inserted in data extension in one field, each value is seperated by comma by default functionality, so i dont want comma, i am replacing the comma value using semicolon with the help of replace function, **but in second checkbox arts after comma is there**, while using replace function that comma also replacing, how to avoid that comma?please guide with code

I have tried with this:

```
set @p = "\s\,+\s\"
set @m = RegExMatch(@travelinterest,@p,0,"IgnoreCase")
set @o = replace(@travelinterest,@m," ;")
```

**but it is not working,please anyone guide me ANSWER**

Comment: so basically you want all commas except the one in "Arts,Culture..."  to be replaced with a semi-colon?

Comment: yes you are right @Gortonington,no i want to replace semicolon, except arts,culture

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but you could do the following:

```
Replace(Replace(@travelinterest,",",";"), "Arts;Culture", "Arts,Culture")
```

This will solve your immediate need.  Otherwise if you needed something a bit more robust so you don't need to add a new replace function each time you need an exception, you can have it insert another unique symbol, like ` or ~ into the parts you want to retain the comma and then use the following:

e.g. use below for your concat:

```
SET @record_product = Concat(@var1, "~" , @var2)
```

and this for your replace:

```
Replace(Replace(@travelinterest,",",";"), "~", ",")
```

Which will replace all tilde's with commas after the other commas were changed to semi-colons.

I am sure there is a much more elegant solution out there via RegEx, but I don't know it and it may be much too complex for the simple issue you are having.

Comment: Replace(Replace(@favouritebcdestination,",",";"), "Arts;Culture", "Arts,Culture") it is not working

Comment: looks like (judging from your RegEx sample), it should be @travelinterest. I will update my answer with that variable.

Comment: i just need one clarification @Gortonington

Comment: I am not sure what your previous comment means @SFDC

Comment: please help me for this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180988/form-page-in-concat-function@Gortonington

Comment: I want to Manually concetanate both travelinterest and Favourite Destination @Gortonington help with some small logic lines=

Comment: prior to moving into further questions, let's focus on this question - If this one is answered, please make sure to mark it as such. If not, please clarify what you still need help on.

Comment: ,actually i want answer for that question that is the correct we have to get manually the answer from page , anyhow i will mark you as best , please help me for that also @ Gortonington